# Google Apps Script inside a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I want to create a extra function for our Company Google Apps.

I want to add the a button functionality in gmail that will forward all selected emails.
Somehow Gmail does not have Bulk Forwarding.

Anyway I know it's possible with a Google Speadsheet and all but it needs to be more friendly then that.

Now companies like streak and boomerang use a chrome Extension to Schedule certain emails.
I know how to get the list/array of selected emails with javascript in a chrome extension.

But after getting that list I want to be able to use the Google Apps Script to get the ThreadID's and collect all their data and Forward the emails.

I know how to get the thread data and forward it seperately in Google apps script.

I have no Idea how to combine these too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible but it will only work on a single account since that is how gas permissions work. Ive called gas from a chrome extension without problems. You need to add a few allowed domains for the ajax call.
Pass the array of threadids as json to a gas content script.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. I guess at first it will be 3 people. plus we only have 15 people on the job so 1 morning worth of work if it comes to that :)  
Is there any special way to add to the extension code? I mean getting the array and passing the array isn't that hard.
parsing the JSON isn't that hard either.. somehow I am just not clear on how to connect? Do I import something? What domains do I allow?

Comment: You will need to make a seoarate extension for each user, each with their own appscript service hard coded. To avoid multiple extensions make a single one and the first time ask each user for their appscript service url which you can save as localStorage

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like a good idea. I will try this today if I have the time in between projects.
I got a simple connection between Extension and GAS now though